# How can I install Pyomo's "extras" using pip?

Tags: pyomo

I am writing because I am having trouble installing [Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/) using `pip` on Python 3.6 on Mac OSX 10.14

I'm following the installation instructions [here](http://www.pyomo.org/installation).

I can successfully execute the first command:

`pip install pyomo`

But when I run into trouble when I'm supposed to run the following command to install additional dependencies:

`pyomo install-extras`

Running this command produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyomo", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/scripting/pyomo_main.py", line 82, in main
    retval = _options.func(_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/scripting/driver_help.py", line 46, in install_extras_exec
    pyutilib.subprocess.run(command, tee=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyutilib/subprocess/processmngr.py", line 690, in run_command
    th.join()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'th' referenced before assignment
```

There is a post about this here on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/i-3uwYvldko) but no solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a documented issue on the github for Pyomo: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/243

They don't appear to have solved the pip installation of pyomo extras.

However, if you have conda installed - https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/

You should be able to use the terminal commands from:

https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

run this in terminal after conda has been successfully installed:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo.extras
```

I know this isn't pip, but it's at least a workaround until pyomo fixes their documentation.

- confirmed working on python 3.x and ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem too (in Ubuntu 18.04).

Try installing it from the git project (https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo):

In Ubuntu 18.04:

```
git clone https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo.git
python3 pyomo/scripts/get_pyomo_extras.py
```

Use the corresponding commands for Mac OSX (I had never used it).

I hope that it works for you.